# Do we need separate tags [triangular-matrix], [triangular-number], or do we overload [triangular] with those meanings?

Tags: discussion, tag-disambiguation

Originally I intended to just suggest the need for [triangular-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular-matrix). But in researching that I found I gigantic mess of multiple unrelated subcategories each involving "*triangular"*. Looking for suggestions on whether to create/abolish each of the following:

1. **"triangular-matrix"** ([1406 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=triangular+matrix)) is a [separate and unrelated meaning, *"a (square) matrix whose entries are zero above(/below) the main diagonal*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix). *"upper-triangular"* ([867 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=upper+triangular)) and *"lower-triangular"* ([704 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=lower+triangular)). So, >2500 questions. Other related terms: "Cholesky decomposition", LU, Gauss-Seidel, sparse (sometimes)... **Suggest needs a separate tag [triangular-matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular-matrix).**
2. Which of the following should we disambiguate with separate tags, and should we apply [triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular) to the other subcategories, or other tags (see below), or not tag some of those at all? (Perhaps [triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular) is too broad and should be abolished?)
3. Existing meaning of **[triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular)**: *"Use this tag when you have a programmatic problem related to coordinates, area, or any other property of a shape that forms a triangle."*
4. One common use on SO is *"CSS triangles"* [3,058 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=CSS+triangle) and I don't think that needs a separate tag, and I wouldn't even tag [triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular) either.
5. Another common use is which HTML/XML character to use for a triangle.
6. Another common use is algorithms to draw a triangle, triangle geometry, calculations, bounding-boxes, transformations, meshes, tessellations, (Sierpinksi Triangle) etc. Is [triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular) ok for all these?
7. **"triangular number"** [(792 SO questions)*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=triangular+number): *"a positive integer which can be written as (N)(N+1)/2"*, which seems to be a common programming challenge, and is about factorization. **Should we create [triangular-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular-number), or should we apply [factorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/factorization) or [number-theory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/number-theory)?**
8. Another number-theory use is [pascals-triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascals-triangle) but that already has its own tag with [165 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pascals-triangle?mixed=1)
9. CrossValidated (CV) has a tag for a much less common specialist meaning, on statistical distributions [triangular-distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular-distribution) [9 questions on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/triangular-distribution?mixed=1)
10. There are surely other meanings (on SO), this was a just a first pass. Probably few/none of those deserve a separate tag.

Suggestions to discuss:

- **"triangular-matrix"** definitely needs a separate tag, since it's unrelated to the other meanings
- **"triangular number"** probably deserves a separate tag, to disambiguate from the other senses
- for the other meanings, do we actively tag **[triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular)** and overload it? or not tag at all? or what?

Notes:

- 4,164 SO questions contain [*triangular*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=triangular). However:
- ...only ~100 SO questions are currently tagged [tag:triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular)
- ~150 CV questions with the term [*triangular matrix*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=triangular+matrix)

Originally motivated by [this question, among others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468869/converting-a-vector-in-r-into-a-lower-triangular-matrix-in-specific-order).

Comment: Do we really need a triangular-matrix tag? *From a programming problem perspective*, is there really a useful distinction to be made between it and just the standard matrix tag?

Comment: I think your question is a little misleading, as the triangular tag is not being used very much at all (less than 100 questions), so it's not really an issue of re-tagging unrelated cases. I'm not sure we really need to do *anything*.

Comment: @River: yes we do. Reason: not all triangular-matrix questions say "triangular matrix", some say "Cholesky decomposition", LU, Gauss-Seidel, sparse, UT, LT... yet are often thematically related.

Comment: @River: you misunderstood my point on [tag:triangular]. It's being underused, and also it's overly broad, but it still is applicable to thousands of questions. I noticed that it's not applicable to triangular-matrix when trying to tag [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48468869/converting-a-vector-in-r-into-a-lower-triangular-matrix-in-specific-order) and found there wasn't any suitable tag to apply, but the tag that autocomplete suggested [tag:triangular], would have been totally wrong. My question is making more than one point...

Comment: "it still is applicable to thousands of questions" that usually is a sign that it is not a good tag.

Comment: I think my main issue is that you're trying to increase use of [tag:triangular]. I don't feel it's a good tag, so I'm glad it's underused. Creation of other tags is a whole separate issue, and should be a different post altogether.

Comment: @River: I'm not necessarily trying to increase use of [tag:triangular]. I commented it's quite broad. If you believe it should be abolished, then go ahead and post an answer making the case for that.

Comment: Even if it were in a separate post, I still don't think triangular-matrix is a good tag. Only about 1/3 of the 2500 questions you show above use even the [tag:matrix] tag. That makes me think your more specific tag would be ignored at an even higher rate.

Comment: @smci I'll go ahead and post an answer summarizing my thoughts.

Comment: @Braiam: as I already researched, [tag:triangular] applies to algorithms to draw a triangle, triangle geometry, calculations, bounding-boxes, transformations, meshes, tessellations, (Sierpinksi Triangle) etc. Can you make specific recommendations (in an answer)? Do you suggest merely deleting [tag:triangular] and leaving it that, or creating subtags (if so which ones)? I'd prefer to see answers, with actual suggestions.

Comment: @River: it would be superfluous to tag [tag:matrix] since that's implied by [tag:triangular-matrix], or indeed countless other terms like 'sparse representation' or 'Cholesky'. There are legitimate tags whose adopt rate is quite low, I don't see that as being a hard-and-fast rule (conversely it's quite weird that [tag:pascals-triangle] has its own little niche tag). In any case people like me (or you) can manually retag questions with appropriate tags, then the use should take off. The motivation behind this question to seek consensus before doing that.

Comment: @River: please don't edit it. The question is not primarily about the tag triangular, it asks multiple things about other possible tags. (There may well be a case for abolishing 'triangular', and that doesn't diminish the case for the other tags I'm asking about in the least.) As to tag compatibility between SO, CV, and other SE sites, my understanding is that's desirable, esp. as questions are sometimes migrated. So does the fact that tag [tag:triangular-distribution] already exists on CV in any way strengthen the case for [tag:triangular-distribution] on SO? even weakly?

Comment: @smci they're different sites. Different sites are about different things and so necessarily have different tags. I don't think it matters in the slightest what tags another site has

Comment: So I edited the question in order to make the genealogy more clear. Here is the intent of my question, and here is how it arose: a) a strong case can be made for [tag:triangular-matrix] since it bundles a group of algorithms and representations. b) It has nothing to do with [tag:triangular], which is a broad jumble of things, yet for a [tag:triangular-matrix] question, the tag autosuggest suggests [tag:triangular], which is a mess. If the decision is to abolish [tag:triangular], that's fine by me. c) In the course of researching all those, seems there's a (separate) case for triangular-number

Answer (score 2):

#### I think we should do nothing

While the [triangular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/triangular) tag is very broad and could be burninated, it's barely used so I don't see this as a pressing issue.

**Tag Creation:**

I think all your listed cases are already described well enough by their current tags, we don't need new tags for these specific cases.

In regards to "triangular-matrix", I don't think it captures a useful subset of questions. Looking at your 2500 questions, it seems like in most cases the triangularity of the matrix doesn't matter for the question. Thus they should just use the matrix tag (which around 1/3 currently do).

The same applies to "triangular-number". It's way too specific and the important (to a programmer) parts can be described with other tags.

Basically these come down to "a tag should be used to describe what the question is *about*, not just what is *in* the question. Your cases might be *in* a few questions, but very few seems to be *about* them.